# ST_Intersects failed with "ERROR: GetGenericCacheCollection: Could not find upper context"

Tags: postgis, st-intersects

When I run this query

```
SELECT ST_Intersects(ST_geomFROMTEXT('POLYGON((105.767292 35.923215,112.165502 37.269499,114.177842 33.956548,113.636058 30.975062,105.393203 30.531638,105.767292 35.923215))', 4326), st_geomfromtext('POINT(114 36)',4326))
```

Then failed with the following Error msg:
ERROR: GetGenericCacheCollection: Could not find upper context
在位置：SQL function "st_intersects" statement 1

While the following query is ok:

```
SELECT ST_Intersects(ST_geomFROMTEXT('POLYGON((105.767292 35.923215,112.165502 37.269499,114.177842 33.956548,113.636058 30.975062,105.393203 30.531638,105.767292 35.923215))', 4326), st_geomfromtext('POINT(115 36)',4326))
```

PostGis Version:
POSTGIS="3.3.2 r8d236eb7d" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="110" GEOS="3.11.1-CAPI-1.17.1" PROJ="7.2.1" GDAL="GDAL 3.3.2, released 2021/09/01 GDAL_DATA not found" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="0.12.1" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.2" (core procs from "2.5.4 r0" need upgrade) RASTER (raster procs from "2.5.4 r0" need upgrade)

But when I run the same queries on another PG Server, It is all ok:

POSTGIS="3.1.4 af77795f7" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="110" GEOS="3.9.1dev-CAPI-1.14.1" PROJ="7.2.1" GDAL="GDAL 3.3.2, released 2021/09/01 GDAL_DATA not found" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="0.15" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.2" WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)" RASTER [UNPACKAGED!] (raster procs from "2.5.4 r0" need upgrade)

Thanks for you help!

Comment: The same error message appears in https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/4695.